# Using python how can I get the rotation of a mesh when rotation has been applied?

Tags: python

I have several meshes in a scene, each mesh is rotated at random angles. I have then applied the rotation so it sets back the rotation value of each mesh to 0,0,0

In python how can I calculate the object rotation for a mesh with there rotation reset to 0,0,0?

Comment: Hello. Well you can't, the rotation is not stored anywhere when you apply it. You can try to infer it if your mesh has specific features along a specific axis (eg a straight wall) where you compute the mean value of the polygon normals, but there is no general case way to achieve what you're trying to do